# What is the origin and earliest recorded usage of 'cock-up'

Tags: etymology, word-usage, offensive-language, phrasal-verbs

In informal British English, the expression 'cock-up' (c.f. the US English 'fuck-up') is used to indicate an error or problem in a situation.

What is the origin of this expression and its etymology? Does anyone know of its use prior to the 1960s?

Comment: As opposed to cocking up your hat :)

Comment: I am getting hats, splints, birds from most years (and graphic porn from 1971) here http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cock+up&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Comment: @Kris - presumably you're not a native (UK/AUS/US) speaker?

In anycase, a quick Google search would get you to these sources:

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cockup

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cock-up

This is old (1791) but I'm not sure the usage here is semantically the same as its modern counterpart: http://www.robertburns.org/works/333.shtml

HTH.

Comment: Should we not place these references in the OP?

Comment: @Kris I don't see why the OP needs to provide a source. It's common knowledge. A quick Google search will confirm it. The answers will supply a source.

Comment: @5arx The Burns quote is not the same semantically.

Comment: @slim: To show his previous research effort and substantiate the question. Frivolous or too broad questions can be closed. See the lone answer for clarification. I did not provide the same answer because it could have been obtained by 'A quick Google search' as you will agree. Please also see tchrist's comment for why I'd seriously suggested closing the post.

Comment: If you'd still expect englishSE to do your homework, please check out http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-coc1.htm and, perhaps, close the question yourself.

Comment: @tchrist - here in England a cock is both what you'd call a 'rooster' and also what you'd call a 'schlong' or 'weiner'. The degree of profanity depends on the context. Cock-up is an attractive usage because it appears edgy but is actually perfectly legitimate.

Comment: What a tragic world this would be if we all did as @Kris advocates and dumped human discourse for Google search.

Comment: @5arx Not here.   A public schoolteacher would be severely censured for using such fowl language in the classroom.

Comment: +1 Heh heh heh. Very good. Or should I say 'egg-cellent' ...?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the phrase "all to c**k" considered profane?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35297/is-the-phrase-all-to-ck-considered-profane)

Comment: I may be wrong about this, but it seems to me Americans are more sensitive to "offensiveness by association" than Brits (cf the attitude of many Americans to *niggardly*). There was originally no connection between *cock-up* and *penis*, and few Brits would perceive it even today.

Comment: The precise form *cock-up* seems to be relatively recent. The earliest I can find is [this one from 1948](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=UHXOAAAAMAAJ&q=%22is+a+cock-up%22&dq=%22is+a+cock-up%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8jk5T77FL8LB0QWz37ilAg&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAA)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - the 'cock' is common to both, but I consider the two forms distinct enough to afford each a dedicated question of its own.

Comment: I would tend to agree with you re: US English speakers' general sensitivity. A country where until relatively recently, *colored* people were segregated from white ones should have a stronger stomach IMHO.

Comment: @5arx: I suppose you would say that, wouldn't you? I did mention *cock-up* in my original answer, and I really don't think there's anything there which goes beyond the [alphadictionary](http://www.alphadictionary.com/blog/?p=57) *set askew, askant, awry* definition I originally linked to. All else is just discussion of US sensitivites (also covered in the original), and the (to me, at least) slightly unusual fact that **cock-up** seems to be actually even later than WW2.

Comment: @5arx Apartheid-style racial segregation was much more of an issue in the slave states of the American South; it was much less of one in the free states of the American North. Nonetheless, there was — and still is — de-facto segregation, in that there are churches, restaurants, etc that were/are functionally exclusively black in their clientele. But we in the North never had separate restrooms and such for “colored” people, and find the very notion just as repugnant as you do. For an interesting story though, check out why the Pentagon has so many restrooms: DC was free, but not VA.

Comment: From what I understand there was a fair degree of segregation in the North and the South, much of it was enforced by invisible state/social machinery. It is debateable whether explicit signage made that much of a difference.

Comment: Confusingly, oppose "bang up": https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bang_up

Answer (score 6):

This "blunder" meaning of *cock-up* has been used before the 1960s, from at least the 1940s in writing.

---

It can be found in the [1950](http://books.google.fi/books?ei=Y0c5T7KAAqyQ4gTGnqyhCw&id=0vkLAQAAIAAJ&q=cock-up#search_anchor) *Sea slang of the twentieth century: Royal Navy, Merchant Navy, yachtsmen, fishermen, bargemen, canalmen, miscellaneous* by Wilfred Granville, which covers the period from [1900 to 1949](http://books.google.com/books?id=0vkLAQAAIAAJ&q=1949#search_anchor).

> **cock-up.** A mess-up, a bungled piece of work. A LASH-UP. (Lower-deck.)
>
> **lash-up.** General confusion caused by a misunderstood order or a bungled job of work. Cf. the Royal Navy's lower-deck term, COCK-UP.

---

Pierre Clostermann's [1948](http://books.google.co.uk/books?ei=8jk5T77FL8LB0QWz37ilAg&id=UHXOAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22is%20a%20cock-up%22&q=cock%20up#search_anchor) *Le Grand Cirque* is one of the very first post-WWII fighter pilot memoirs:

> Hullo Filmstar Leader, sorry old boy, there is a **cock-up** about the Typhies. Do your best if you can without !

---

*Workers in Stalin's Russia* by M. L. Berneri ([1944](http://books.google.fi/books?id=HYzXAAAAMAAJ&q=%22cock%20up%22#search_anchor)):

> The journey of approx. 500 miles took us five days, and has been known to take ten days. As we had to take food for this time we travelled rather like a person moving house. There was a **cock-up** about transport to take us across the ice to the station

---

Finally, the term isn't particularly offensive. It's been used scores of times in [UK parliament](http://www.theyworkforyou.com/search/?s=%22cock-up%22), most [recently](http://www.theyworkforyou.com/debates/?id=2012-02-02a.995.5&s=%22cock-up%22#g996.0) by Peter Bone:

> Last Sunday I attended Indian republic day at the Wellingborough Hindu Association, yet the same week we learn that a £20 billion fighter contract has been lost to, of all people, the French. We now know that the lead bidder was not the British Prime Minister or the British Government, but the Germans. What on earth do they know about cricket and curries? Why was the British Government not leading on that? How did the Secretary of State allow such a **cock-up**?

Answer (score 4):

Cock up Origin:

Cock up is an innocent expression meaning error used by printers and others, including poachers. This latter group could well be the true origin since it is claimed that, if you startle a pheasant that you're stalking, then it will squawk and the noise sounds like cock up.

Alternative: Cocking a flintlock pistol. If not cocked up there was likely to be a disaster when the trigger was pulled.

Alternative: The arrows of traditional English long bows had three feathers. One of these, named the cock feather, had to be positioned away from the line of the bow stave, otherwise it would hit the bow stave and affect the flight of the arrow to produce a cock up.

Alternative: When a fermented barrel of wine is ready to be run-off for bottling, a stop-cock is driven into the barrel and a sample is tasted to check for quality. If the wine has turned sour, the cock is twisted upside down showing that the barrel is not to be used.

Alternative: In the ranks of soldiers practicing manoeuvres with their flint-lock (or percussion-cap) rifles, it was not unusual to hear a rifle discharge when it shouldn't have done. Some rifles lacked the trigger guard that is now mandatory, and trigger mechanisms in general were not to be trusted. Subsequently, when the rifles where slammed and jerked from position to position, any recruit who had eagerly cocked their rifle in error, would be likely to inadvertently fire the rifle. The remark would be "well, that was a cock up"... the mistake becoming known as a cock up and giving name to many other accidental happenings.

Alternative: Cock up is a well-known nautical expression. The Cock is the upper foremost corner of a gaff sail rigged sail. The Head is the upper edge and the peak the upper after corner. When fully raised the peak is higher than the cock. When raising the gaff, 2 gangs will operate the halyards both on the cock end and peak end of the gaff. It is most important that they raise the gaff horizontal, otherwise this large piece of timber will slew sideways into the mast (it has a metal ring round the mast to stop it coming away completely) and jams fast and then becomes impossible to either raise or lower. This is most acute if the cock is above the peak hence a cock up. It is quite easily done if the 2 gangs are not paying attention to each other.

Comment: Wow that is comprehensive. And Speeeedy!

 Many thanks. Don't suppose you have any idea which of these was first recorded?

Comment: 2 3 and 4 don't seem true/logical; I like 5 best.  But in any case, +1 for a comprehensive answer.

Comment: These are all rather fanciful derivations. The word *cock* has a very broad spread of meaning. Per [my answer here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35297), the one that matters in *cock-up* is more related to the usage in a *cocked hat*, or when an angler *cocks his float*.

Comment: Or possibly it's related to cock=penis and just an obseccity?

Comment: Do you have any reliable references for these? Most of them sound like made-up folk etymologies.

Answer (score 2):

One of the (many) dictionary definitions for *cock* is:

- Nonsense (British Slang)

So to *cock up* is to make a cock of something.

Note that the phrase can be used as a verb or, hyphenated, a noun:

> He's going to cock up that piece of work.
>
> This project is a complete cock-up.

Also it can be broken up as you'd expect:

> Be careful when folding the souffle, or you'll cock the texture up.

You can also say:

> You've made a complete cock of that.
>
> Everything about this effort has gone to cock.

... with that same, non-obscene, meaning for cock.

To answer the question fully, we need an early reference to "cock" meaning nonsense. I suspect it is *very* early.

Answer (score 2):

The OED has no use of *cock-up* in this sense before 1948, and even then only in a dictionary of Service slang.  But *cock* in the sense of 'a made-up story or *canard*' is nineteenth century if not before (it's difficult to be sure whether earlier uses are shortened versions of *cock-and-bull* or *poppycock*); and in the sense of *brawl* (presumably from cockfighting), it's much earlier.  It seems to be a recent extension of the word, but only a small change.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to recall hearing Melvyn Bragg say that *cock-up* is borrowed from Hindi. However, I have not been able to find any confirmation. There are a few users of South Asian origin on this site so perhaps some confirmation, or denial, will be forthcoming.

There are, or were, plenty of expressions from Hindi current in the days of empire, and for many years thereafter, but some of them appear to have dropped out of use. When I was at school we had to hand over a dinner chit to get fed; in this case the chit was a plastic token. *Chit* or *chitti* are clearly Hindi in origin; I hardly ever hear the words these days.

I recently told an employment agent that I had grown out of my suit so I would have to attend the interview in mufti. The agent had to check the meaning of *mufti*. Perhaps we should bring back compulsory military service to remind people of these Hindi-based words.

Even the word *khaki* leads to puzzlement sometimes even though it regularly appears on clothes labels. I even saw it in foot-high letters on the front page of the Sun newspaper recently, but perhaps people take no notice of newspapers these days.

Comment: Interesting. I'm of South Asian origin too, I will investigate further and ask older family members about this.

Agree re: Hindi/Indian loanwords. The list is a very long one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_Hindi_or_Urdu_origin

Re: newspapers - No one takes much notice of the Sun, that's for sure.